# Algorithm for sharing jobs by two executors

Tags: algorithm, queue

I encountered the following problem, while testing some web-site:

> John and Mary founded J&M publishing house and bought two old printers
>   to equip it. Now they have their first commercial deal - to print a
>   document consisting of N pages. It appears that printers work at
>   different speed. One produces a page in X seconds and other does it in
>   Y seconds. So now company founders are curious about minimum time they
>   can spend on printing the whole document with two printers.

(taken from here http://codeabbey.com/index/task_view/two-printers)

I thought it is the problem for greedy algorithm, but it is told that N could be up to billion, so there perhaps is some simpler solution which I could not see. Could I come to solution dividing them in proportion to X and Y somehow?

Comment: This seems to be a math question rather than algorithm question. The job distribution would be `YN/(X+Y)` pages to `X`, `XN/(X+Y)` pages to `Y`. Total time would be `XYN/(X+Y)` which is optimal (note that it is equivalent to `N/(1/X + 1/Y)`. Since `YN/(X+Y)` might not be integer, you can just calculate a few values (if `X` is rounded up and `Y` is rounded down, and vice versa) , then take the minimum.

Comment: Oh, I see now! I surely came to same formulas, but I did not invent how to deal with integer results. Thanks to you, it became clear: I need to round down both of them and then there would be only 1 job left which should be assigned by greedy principle. Looks like this could be extrapolated to K queues... Thanks again!

Comment: I've answered your question then, I would really appreciate it if you can upvote and accept my answer ^^

Comment: Yes, of course. I was surprised myself that you did not write this as answer at once :)
However it appeared I must gain a bit reputation to vote for your answer, sorry for a little delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a math question rather than algorithm question. The job distribution would be `YN/(X+Y)` pages to `X`, `XN/(X+Y)` pages to `Y`. Total time would be `XYN/(X+Y)` which is optimal (note that it is equivalent to `N/(1/X + 1/Y)`. Since `YN/(X+Y)` might not be integer, you can just calculate a few values (if `X` is rounded up and `Y` is rounded down, and vice versa) , then take the minimum. Or as you said, you can round down both and give any remaining jobs to the faster machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(int(input())):
    x,y,n = list(map(float, input().split()))
    x_1 = int(y*n / (x+y))
    y_1 = int(x*n/ (x+y))
    n = n - (x_1 + y_1)
    x_ans = int(max( (x_1 + n)* x, y_1 * y))
    y_ans = int(max( x_1 * x, (y_1 + n) * y))

    print(min(x_ans,y_ans),end=' ')
```