# Trying to round big numbers on this specific task

Tags: c#, rounding

I`m trying to solve a puzzle:
http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/two-printers

The problem is that I get problems with the rounding, and I`m not sure where the problem is and how much the number should be rounded before performing the operations.
So here is the input for the first 4 test cases (first number is the seconds of the first printer to print a page, the second is the same for the second printer, and the number of pages to be printed):

15 15 46491255

5900 13309 60565

13 3 75408735

80025 84130 10370

Here are my answers:
348684413 / 247579340 / 183808792 / 425305709

Here are the correct answers:
348684420 / 247581700 / 183808794 / 425332875

Here is my code:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        string[] container = new string[3];
        double[] results = new double[n];
        double printer1, printer2, pages;
        double x, y;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
            container = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

            printer1 = double.Parse(container[0]);
            printer2 = double.Parse(container[1]);
            pages = double.Parse(container[2]);

            x = (1 / printer1) + (1 / printer2);
            y = Math.Round((pages / x), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);


            results[i] = y;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(results[i] + " ");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This question has already been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176589/algorithm-for-sharing-jobs-by-two-executors

Comment: Yes, but this one includes clearly written and nicely formatted code. I wish all questions were asked this well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with the code:

The minor problem is that you always want to round up to the next integer, but that's not what `MidpointRounding` does. You want to use `Ceiling`.

But the major problem is that the code doesn't take into account that the printers can print only *whole pages*. Imagine an extreme example of 12 40 6:

```
| Time | Printer 1 | Printer 2 | Total   |
| (sec)| (pages)   | (pages)   | (pages) |
+------------------------------+---------|
|  12  |  1        |  0.3      |  1.3    |
|  24  |  2        |  0.6      |  2.6    |
|  36  |  3        |  0.9      |  3.9    |
|  40  |  3.333    |  1.0      |  4.333  |
|  48* |  4        |  1.2      |  5.2    |
|  60  |  4        |  1.667    |  5.667  |
|  80  |  4        |  2        |  6      |
```

Notice what happens at 48 seconds: the first printer has completed 4 pages, while the other is still printing its second page. Ideally, and according to the code, the first printer could speed things up by "helping" the slower one with the remainder of its second page, finishing in 6/(1/12 + 1/40) = just under 56 seconds. But in reality the printers can't share pages; each one must print only complete pages, so we have no choice but to leave the first printer idle for 22 seconds while the other completes its page.

But we can do better if we anticipate this and give the slower printer only a single page:

```
| Time | Printer 1 | Printer 2 | Total   |
| (sec)| (pages)   | (pages)   | (pages) |
+------------------------------+---------|
|  12  |  1        |  0.3       |  1.3   |
|  24  |  2        |  0.6       |  2.6   |
|  36  |  3        |  0.9       |  3.9   |
|  40* |  3.333    |  1         |  4.333 |
|  48  |  4        |  1         |  5     |
|  60  |  5        |  1         |  6     |
```

Here we leave the slower printer idle after one page, realizing we'll finish in only 60 seconds if we let the faster one print an extra page. So, depending on the relative speeds and the number of pages, and recognizing that the printers can share the work only in units of complete pages, it may be wiser *not* to give the slower one another page when it finishes, because the faster one will "catch up" in the end.

The way to solve this is to figure out how many pages to give each printer. Imagine the pages as one long continuous sheet of paper. Each printer starts at one end, and they "race" toward the middle as they print. When they meet, the faster one will have printed 5 × 40/(12 + 40) = just over 3.8 pages. But in reality, of course, it can handle only complete pages, so we need to see which is better: to let it print the extra 0.2 page, or to stop it after only 3 pages and let the slower one print the 0.8 page. In this case it's clear that we should give the 0.2 page to the faster printer, but we can solve the general case by noting that 0.2(12) < 0.8(40).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you are not looking for a full code answer to the problem specified since the site that you pointed to is generally for people who want to learn how to solve these kinds of problems.

Your issue is not in the rounding of your answer.  Rather, it is in your algorithm.

If you check your algorithm against the examples given on the site, you'll see that your algorithm does not work.

For the second example of "3 5 4", your program gives 7.5 (prior to rounding).  No matter which way you round 7.5, you are not going to get the correct answer of 9.

Either printer1 or printer2 will end up being the long pole, depending upon the input data, and that printer will end up with an integer number of pages (printers cannot share a page to print) -- there's no rounding involved here at all.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys. The truth is, even I solved the task, I don`t feel like it was totally my achievement....It was even too hard to follow your explanations, even tho, they were really well written. 
After a day of solving, here`s what I got at the end. I`ll copy only the Algo part of it:

```
 double printedPages1 = Math.Ceiling((printer2 * pages) / (printer1 + printer2));
  double printedPages2 = Math.Ceiling((printer1 * pages) / (printer1 + printer2));
        if (printedPages1 * printer1 < printedPages2 * printer2)
        {
            time = Math.Ceiling(printedPages1 * printer1);
        }
        else
        {
            time = Math.Ceiling(printedPages2 * printer2);
        }


        results[i] = time; // I add the result(time) in an array
```

Well maybe not the best way of doing it...If you have any suggestions please post :)